# Prove (2^n - 1) via induction

Tags: recursion, induction

I have this program that, when run, has prints in this pattern:

a(0) = 0

a(1) = 1

a(2) = 2 + a(1) = 3

a(3) = 3 + a(2) + a(1) = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7

a(4) = 4 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 15

At this point I observe that there is a pattern of it becoming O(2^n - 1). However, I am not sure if this is a valid proof by induction. An idea I had was:

a(n)= n + a(n-1) + a(n-2) + ... + 1 = 2^n - 1

But from here the pattern for the terms are not very clear to me. I know the first term is n (in our code, this is due to a for loop that prints a statement n times), and due to recursion I know I will be summing the previous values but I don't know what a(n-1), a(n-2), etc. are in terms of n.

Comment: No, this is not valid proof by induction. You don't need to go beyond 0. If by assuming that f(n) is true, you are able to prove f(n+1) is true, then all you need is to prove f(0) is true. If f(0) is true, then f(1) is true. If f(1) is true, then f(2) is true and so on and so forth.

Comment: I think I understand that, but I don't know how to express the function for f(n) such that I can prove that it also works for f(n+1). I don't know, for example, what a(n-1) or a(n-2) is in this pattern, I just know that the sum of my terms comes to 2^n - 1.

Comment: I don't think this a programming problem at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem at all.